# Error in Test Library : Creating keyword 'Confirm Dates' failed: Keyword with same name defined multiple times

Tags: python-2.7, robotframework

I have created a set of robot framework libraries to use in my automated tests.
I am now facing the sale error when running any of my tests.

```
Error in test library 'HomePage': Creating keyword 'Confirm Dates' failed:  Keyword with same name defined multiple times.
```

This error is generated for every keyword in each library I have created.
My code did not change and even by reverting back the code I am still facing this error.

In my code I am using the page object pattern so I have page libraries and components libraries. I am calling component libraries in my page lib this way :

```
@robot_alias("search_for_in_search_bar")
def search_for_in_search_bar(self, dest, arrivaldate, departuredate):
    self.searchbar.search_weekends_for(dest, arrivaldate, departuredate)
    return SerpPage.SerpPage()
```

So this a kind of embedded keyword?

Thanks
Zied

Comment: Robot Framework supports having same keyword from several files so duplicate keyword should not be your problem: http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#handling-keywords-with-same-names. Are you using any keywords with embedded variables? You could also increase log level to debug or trace with -L option.

Comment: goog to know that keyword names are not my problem, i do have keywords with embedded variables how this could relate to my error? Adding -L trace shows the first keyword I am calling and its argument so no more clue about the problem

Comment: Pekka Klärk has this to say about embedded keywords: https://github.com/robotframework/robotframework/issues/2098

Comment: I was looking at this issue and I am not exactly in the same situation but quite similar, I am using the page object library and using componentts. In my page keyword I call a component keyword.